# C# List.Add() in method as a Parameter. Different list types(int and string)

Tags: c#, list, collections

```
//Program
List<string> newList1 = new List<string>;
List<int> newList2 = new List<int>;
AddToList(newList1);
AddToList(newList2);

//Method
static void AddToList(List<object"?"> list)
{
list.Add();
}
```

So how do i make this? I don't wanna make two different methods. How can it be in one Method?

Okay, then. What should i do with that?

```
    static void List_ShowInfo<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        foreach(Person i in list)
        {
            i.ShowInfo();
        }
    }
```

It's telling me, that i can't convert Type 'T' to 'Person'
Person it's my class

```
        static void List_AddToList<T>(List<T> list, StreamReader file)
    {
        string s;
        while ((s = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            list.Add(new List<T>(s)); <---------------
        }
    }
```

it's telling me, that i can't convert string to int in "s"
I wouldn't make a post if i find something in google. But i didn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

Define `AddToList` as a generic method:

```
static void AddToList<T>(List<T> list) 
{
}
```

Now you can call the method wih a type argument:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
AddToList<int>(list);
```

But because in most cases the compiler is smart enough to figure out the type of `T` you can omit the type argument and just call

```
AddToList(list);
```

Edit: Answers to follow up questions:

To iterate over the list use `T` as type as you would with non-generic types.

```
static void List_ShowInfo<T>(List<T> list)
{
    foreach (T item in list) // list is List<T>, so all items are of type T
    {
       // Do something with item
    }
}
```

In your example:

```
static void List_AddToList<T>(List<T> list, StreamReader file)
{
    string s;
    while ((s = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        list.Add(new List<T>(s)); <---------------
    }
}
```

You are construction your list wrong:
 1. You are using a `string` here, but list accepts `int`: Take a look at the [list constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__)
2. If you want to add strings to the list, you probably want to use `List<string>` instead of `List<T>`.

Also take a look at the [Genercis section in the C# Programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)